# [Windows 10, Outlook]: Prevent desktop notifications when receiving calendar response emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

One of my new responsibilities at work is scheduling weekly team meetings. Our team uses Outlook calendar to schedule meetings. Since the team is made up of 20+ people, I am now being spammed with 20+ "Accepted: Team Meeting" emails daily. I've been told from who I'm taking over from to continue allowing meeting responses because that's what people are used to.

To preserve my sanity, I have created a rule that filters all of these calendar responses into a "Meeting Responses" folder. However, this does not fix one crucial problem, the Windows 10 desktop notifications. Every time I receive one of these emails I get a notification from Windows 10. I do not want to receive a Windows notification when I receive a meeting response email in Outlook, but I still need to get notifications when I receive any other type of email otherwise I would probably start missing important emails. Is it possible to say configure Outlook so when an email is sent to a folder or is of a specific type I will not get a notification in Windows about it?

Answer (score 1):

Meeting responses is the way Outlook works.  Filtering email responses the way you are doing is a reasonable thing to do.

To turn off the Alert, right click on the Outlook Icon and uncheck

"Show new Mail Desktop Alert"

That will turn off all notifications. (You cannot have some notifications ON and some OFF - that cannot be done in native Outlook).

[image]

Comment: Agree, you cannot disable specific notifications. It controls all your Outlook notifications.